# SQL: Find duplicate records, but only return latest duplicate record?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.1

I'm trying to find duplicate transmissions in our database, in this case, to find where a transmitter transmitted the same data multiple times in a row (3 or more)

I've tried this query, which gets me close, but returns one record per period of duplicate readings per transmitter, when I only want the most recent duplicate reading period

```sql
select transmitter_id,
       count(*)        as number_of_duplicate_readings,
       total_reading,
       max(transmissions.created_at) as latest_duplicate_reading
from transmissions
group by transmitter_id, total_reading
having count(*) > 3
order by latest_duplicate_reading desc;
```

```
+--------------+----------------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|transmitter_id|number_of_duplicate_readings|total_reading|latest_duplicate_reading|
+--------------+----------------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|205           |50                          |0            |2020-08-17 13:44:03     |
|204           |27                          |0            |2020-08-17 13:44:01     |
|202           |33                          |0            |2020-08-17 13:43:56     |
|200           |27                          |0            |2020-08-17 13:43:52     |
|197           |27                          |0            |2020-08-17 13:43:45     |
|196           |42                          |0            |2020-08-17 13:43:43     |
|194           |43                          |0            |2020-08-17 13:43:39     |
|193           |11                          |0            |2020-08-17 13:43:36     |
|192           |27                          |0            |2020-08-17 13:43:35     |
|505           |37                          |830          |2020-08-05 23:59:28     |
+--------------+----------------------------+-------------+------------------------+
```

If I order by transmitter ID, the issue becomes aparent:

```
+--------------+----------------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|transmitter_id|number_of_duplicate_readings|total_reading|latest_duplicate_reading|
+--------------+----------------------------+-------------+------------------------+
|2             |25                          |300          |2019-09-25 23:09:04     |
|2             |4                           |310          |2019-09-29 23:18:58     |
|2             |5                           |320          |2019-10-04 23:25:27     |
|3             |7                           |15670        |2020-02-06 23:25:14     |
|3             |4                           |16990        |2020-02-24 23:08:26     |
|3             |24                          |19810        |2020-04-13 23:30:59     |
|3             |15                          |19830        |2020-04-28 23:50:35     |
|3             |12                          |20160        |2020-05-19 23:33:27     |
|3             |8                           |20170        |2020-05-27 15:54:51     |
|3             |6                           |20180        |2020-06-21 23:45:22     |
+--------------+----------------------------+-------------+------------------------+
```

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish what I want in MySQL / MariaDB, or will I need to filter this further in other code to accomplish what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data would really help.  It is not clear what you mean by "duplicate readings per transmitter, when I only want the most recent duplicate reading period".  How do you define "duplicate"?

Comment: if you want unique transmitter_ids why are you including the total_reading column in grouping?

Comment: What column of the data should we look at to understand what a duplicate value is?

Comment: My desired output is to only have one record for transmitter 2, which would be for duplicate reading 320 from 2019-10-04, in the second example. I want to find the most recent duplicated transmission, as I don't care about old duplicates

Comment: The duplicate value is any transmission with total_reading being the same with the same transmitter_id

Comment: So whenever I find a total_reading value for a transmitter_id twice in the table, it's a duplicate? Even if one row is from 2015 and the other from 2020? Or are you looking for the same value in the same day? Or the same value in consecutive rows?

Comment: a meter can only count up, so you can't have a reading for a transmitter that goes down then back up

Comment: Ah, I see. And you already find all duplicates, but from this result you only want the latest  entry per transmitter. Are you using MariaDB or MySQL? Which version?

Comment: MySQL 5.1, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunate. Then you must use your query twice. I'll write an answer...

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL 5.1 you have no analytic function (`MAX OVER` etc.) available, nor even a `WITH` clause. The only option I see there is copy & paste. Use about the same query twice, once to find all duplicates, once to check for later duplicates.

```
select 
  transmitter_id,
  count(*) as number_of_duplicate_readings,
  total_reading,
  max(transmissions.created_at) as latest_duplicate_reading
from transmissions t
group by transmitter_id, total_reading
having count(*) > 3
and not exists
(
  select null
  from transmissions t2
  group by t2.transmitter_id, t2.total_reading
  having count(*) > 3
  and t2.transmitter_id = t.transmitter_id
  and max(t2.transmissions.created_at) > t.latest_duplicate_reading
)
order by latest_duplicate_reading desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm getting an error that it doesn't know what t.latest_duplicate_reading is in the second query, any ideas?

Comment: Hm, maybe we can't access that name in the `HAVING` clause yet (although their docs say so). Does `and max(t2.transmissions.created_at) > max(t.transmissions.created_at)` work?

Comment: t2.transmissions.created_at isn't valid syntax, I tried `and max(t2.created_at) > t.created_at` and it says created_at must be in the group by or aggregated

Comment: Ah, probably it's just the t. `latest_duplicate_reading` is not a column of `t`, of course. So just  `and max(t2.transmissions.created_at) > latest_duplicate_reading`. Sorry. Does this work now?